# Chrome works but on FF, My footer is hidden- padding on bottom not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have `padding-bottom:40px;` on the bottom of one of my wrapper divs so as to allow my position absolute "designed by" text to show at the bottom of the page.

It works in Chrome, but in Firefox, the padding-bottom has no effect and the wrapper hits the bottom of the page directly.

You can view the site here:

http://ellisfinancialcorp.com/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey Connor, welcome to StackOverflow.  You should post your relevant code here so people can more easily help (ie other CSS/HTML you think may be contributing to the issue).  Furthermore, could you elaborate a bit more on the problem?  I see no difference in FF 23 and Chrome 24.

Comment: You have a problem on Internet Explorer as well, i recommend you to check your styles and use the debug tools on your browser, F12 should bring them on most of them.

Comment: Confirming comment of GrailsGuy, the only difference I see is that the wrapper is higher in FireFox. Due to form elements being higher. Atleast for me.

Comment: Did the answer below fix your issue?

Comment: Answer didn't fix the issue but introduced new ones... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `bottom: 0` from your footer

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;  <==// Remove this
    color: #EDEDED;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 100;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This makes the footer appear on Firefox, but it doesn't slip behind everything else like it does on Chrome.

Comment: Wait... I'm on Chrome 29.  Is that beta?  Let me try this on another chrome version and I'll get back to you, perhaps something is working on chrome because I have the beta version.

Comment: I ended up switching the code to something else completely.  Thanks for your help anyways.